# Naming a problem with multiple regression curves

Tags: regression, mixed-model, multiple-regression, terminology

I've got a "naming" problem:
I've got some individuals (say, a hundred), and for *each* individual I record 10 points to obtain a regression curve. I want to test if those regression curves will have roughly the same shape (or just general trend) for each individual. How this situation is called? Multiple regression is something different and every key-term I can think of to ask google just refers to multiple regression. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The best way to model it depends on the specifics of your problem, but here are some pointers:

- A [mixed model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model) with a random slope for the individual can *both* account for the dependency in your data caused by repeated measure of the same individuals, *and* give you an estimate of the extent to which the progression differs per individual (the estimated random variance);
- Since you mention a regression 'curve', I would suggest modeling the progression over time with a [spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)). This allows you to flexibly model non-linear progression over time with the only assumption that the progression is smooth.
- You can combine these approaches by estimating a random slope for the spline coefficients of time. Note that this is very costly in terms of degrees of freedom, so you may want to keep the spline degree low.

There are many good questions and answers on this site about the use of splines in regression analysis. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/splines?tab=Frequent) are the most frequently visited ones.